# The tail upper bound for random matrix

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-matrices

Let $A$ be an n by n GOE (Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble) matrix. Define $\|A\|_{op}=\sup_{\|v\|=1}\langle v, Av\rangle$.

We have the following concentration inequality: (see https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiz4d6LuuD6AhUHlIkEHWT_DhIQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fterrytao.files.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F02%2Fmatrix-book.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1wbeiabsuEb4DfHXHjoUJK)

> there exist constants $C,c>0$ so that for $x>0$,
> $$
> P(\|A\|_{op}-E[\|A\|_{op}]\ge x)\le Ce^{-cnx^2}.
> $$

We know that $E[\|A\|_{op}]\to 2$ a.s. (see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-16/issue-4/Necessary-and-Sufficient-Conditions-for-Almost-Sure-Convergence-of-the/10.1214/aop/1176991594.full)

Question:

From above results, can we say that
there exist constants $C,c>0$ so that for $x>0$
$$
P(\|A\|_{op}\ge x+2)\le Ce^{-cnx^2}.
$$

So do we have
$$
P(\|A\|_{op}\ge x)\le Ce^{-cn(x-2)^2}.
$$

Comment: Your final inequality only necessarily holds for $x>2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Can we say for x large enough, $P(\|A\|_{op} \ge x)\le Ce^{-cnx^2}$?